# run kibana failed on virtual machine

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to install kibana on my virtual machine. When I start kibana, the errors as below:

> vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/elasticsearch-2.1.1/plugins/kibana-4.1.1-linux-x64$ ./bin/kibana
>   {"name":"Kibana","hostname":"vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64","pid":13645,"level":50,"err":{"message":"unknown error","name":"Error","stack":"Error: unknown error\n    at respond (/home/vagrant/elasticsearch-2.1.1/plugins/kibana-4.1.1-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:237:15)\n    at checkRespForFailure (/home/vagrant/elasticsearch-2.1.1/plugins/kibana-4.1.1-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/transport.js:203:7)\n    at HttpConnector. (/home/vagrant/elasticsearch-2.1.1/plugins/kibana-4.1.1-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/connectors/http.js:156:7)\n    at IncomingMessage.bound (/home/vagrant/elasticsearch-2.1.1/plugins/kibana-4.1.1-linux-x64/src/node_modules/elasticsearch/node_modules/lodash-node/modern/internals/baseBind.js:56:17)\n    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)\n    at _stream_readable.js:944:16\n    at process._tickCallback (node.js:442:13)"},"msg":"","time":"2016-01-30T10:15:48.111Z","v":0}

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **[Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/downloads/kibana) 4.1.4 Compatible with Elasticsearch 1.4.4 - 1.7**

but my Elasticsearch version is 2.x. So just use the latest version kibana.